# Creating Application logs using Azure App Service (Web App) Diagnostic Logs does not fire blob creation event

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have a Azure Web App and I have turned on **Diagnostic Logging** so that I can log my Application trace message as diagnostic log. I am using a .net logger lib for diagnostic logging that adds the Informational debug or audit trace message from web app methods to the diagnostic log blob storage account container.

I noticed that the diagnostic logs add two containers inside blob. One for **Application Log** and another for **Web log** when diagnostic logging is turned on in the App Service (Web App).

One of the blob container it creates is in CAPITAL LETTER and another one is in small letter. The blob container with small letter case name is the one which contains application logs as per my understanding.

Now I have created an event Grid Subscription for 'Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated' event on Blob storage. And I am using a Function (with HTTP trigger) as an endpoint while creating the subscription in Event Grid for this blob creation event. I am also filtering on the blob creation event and plan to also include filter for subject names to ensure I only receive blob creation events for Application log. I have verified that the Application log with my Application audit or trace or diagnostic log is there in blob container (all small case letters) with all the details I am sending from Application.

Now the weird thing I am observing is that in my Azure serverless function (when it is fired as a result for blob file creation), when I am logging the request data (the input I have received), I am only receiving events from Web Log (the container name with all capital letters case ) and so far I am not able to see any blob creation event fired for Application log. I noticed this based on the "subject" field which contains the file path of the newly created blob.

**So my question is why I am not receiving the blob creation event for Application log?**

Here is the Azure CLI script to create the subscription which use Blob Storage account resource ID:

> endpoint= [function-endpoint]
>
> includeEvents=Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated
>
> **az eventgrid event-subscription create**
>   --resource-id  **$storageid**
>   --name **alert-blog-storage-created**
>   --endpoint  **$endpoint**
>   --included-event-types $includeEvents

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-quickstart?toc=%2Fazure%2Fevent-grid%2Ftoc.json) as a reference which I used to create my Event Grid subscription.

Comment: why not just using azure application insights ?

Comment: How does App insight help ? Can it send (or stream) all my Application log (only) to both Blob storage for retention of 3 year (have some compliance to meet) and also to Log Analytic at the same time?

Comment: Yes it supporting continous export to a storage account: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry